# Trying to retrieve filename from pytest.ini

Tags: python, pytest

I'm trying to retrieve a filename from a pytest.ini file. It was initially hardcoded but now I have placed this in a pytest.ini file. Firstly, is this the correct approach for things like filenames? I am trying to read it but I am getting errors.

Here is my pytest.ini:

```
    [pytest]
    cards_file = data/cards.csv
```

Here is my function:

```
@staticmethod
def get_card_details():
    filename = pytest.config.getini("cards_file")
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        rows = list(reader)[1:]
        
        return random.choice(rows)
```

This is the error:

```
E       AttributeError: module pytest has no attribute config. Did you mean: 'Config'?
```

When I change this to `Config` I get this error:

```
E       TypeError: Config.getini() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
```

What is the argument 'name' that is required? I could not find this in the docs.

WHat is the difference between `Config.getini()` and `config.getini()`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By executing pytest.Config.getini("cards_file") you are trying to use it as a classmethod, which won't work because you must call method from the instance of Config class.

To retrieve the cardname, first add hook to your conftest.py:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addini('cards_file', 'Path to a cards file')
```

Then in your test you can access it via [pytestconfig fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#std-fixture-pytestconfig)

```
def test_one(pytestconfig):
    filename = pytestconfig.getini(name="cards_file")
    print(filename)
```

Comment: With this i'm getting an error - "Failed: Fixture 'pytest_addoption' called directly. Fixtures are not meant to be called directly,
but are created automatically when test functions request them as parameters."